# What is the equivalent of a pagefile in Linux in general?

Tags: partitioning, swap

I'm just starting Linux in general and being a Windows user, I would like to ask if what is the equivalent of the pagefile in Windows in Linux? I know swap, and I know it can only be created to be a separate partition (correct me if I'm wrong). Is there like a custom file (like the pagefile in Windows) in which i could store in a custom location that acts like swap? Basically I like to create a swap like function that saves in a file (like Windows can store pagfiles in none/any drives you have) and how to do it (like script to create in any location i want at startup?)

Comment: You might want to have a look at `man mkswap`, `man swapon` and maybe [swapspace](http://pqxx.org/development/swapspace/).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I have looked into this mkswap, swapon, swapiness and I think this is what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swapfiles do exist in Linux, <s>and are said to be a new default with Ubuntu in a future version (probably 18.04, not sure)</s> and have been made a default as of 17.04

From this article, pretty much the same applies to Ubuntu: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/swap#Swap_file

As root (`sudo su`), run

`fallocate -l 512M /swapfile` to create a 512 MB swapfile, for example

Permissions need to be set with `chmod 600 /swapfile`

Then it's made into an actual swapfile with `mkswap /swapfile`

You can activate it now with `swapon /swapfile`

And activate on boot by adding `/swapfile none swap defaults 0 0` to /etc/fstab

The swap file can be whatever size you want, you can use 8G to make is 8 gigs (or 8192M if you're picky)

I hope this answers your question

Comment: "swapfile" got introduced as default on 17.04 ;)